# How do I convert a function to sigma notation when there is a nested and lagging summation within the function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

I am trying to simplify the following function into summation form: $$f(x) = \frac{x_1}{x_0}+\frac{x_2}{x_0-x_1}+\frac{x_3}{x_0-x_1-x_2}+...+\frac{x_n}{x_0-x_1-x_2-...-x_{n-1}}.$$

However, I am unsure as to how to best simplify the notation as it involves two parts that are iterating, the denominator summation lagging behind the numerator's summation. The closest that I can think of is

$$f(x)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{x_i}{x_0-\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}x_j}$$

but I think this simplification lacks clarity and my gut (and brain) is saying that this isn't correct use of notation either.

If necessary for simplification, here is more context and assumptions. This equation was created through conservation of mass, thus the following conditions must hold:

1. All values of $x$ are positive
2. The initial state, $x_0$, cannot be zero
3. $x_0\geq \sum^{n}_{k=1} x_k $

Thanks in advance for any advice or help <3

Comment: Be careful about the nested expression. Are you sure it gives you $x_0 - x_1$ when $i = 1$ in the other summation? $\quad$ Also, generally avoid having your notation do double duty. Do the sum over $j$ for the nested expression.

Comment: @peterwhy thanks, notation is fixed and updated

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, notation is fixed and updated. Using the updated solution now in the edit, I solved a test case of n=4 and got the correct solution. Is there anything else that can be done to simplify this equation a tad more?

Comment: IMO Either version is as simplified as it would ever be. I don't see a way for terms to cancel out, though I might be incorrect.

Comment: Ah, actually you could combine $x_1 / x_0$ into the expression, so that's a "simplification".  Remember that the empty sum is 0.

Comment: @brycon2: The sum in the denominator needs to start with lower limit $j=1$. Everything else looks fine.